# Export Premiere Pro Camera Track Data to Blender?

Tags: scripting, camera, tracking

I'm new to Premiere Pro, but I understand that it has a camera tracking capability. Is it possible to extract this data and feed it into Blender, [as can be done in After Effects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=el_n1UfPL_M)?

Answer (score 1):

Since Premiere Pro is closed-source, you'd have to find documentation on its API or its data format first. Just use Blender's camera [motion tracking](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/movie_clip_editor/tracking/index.html) features instead.